# Note that is played along with another chord

Tags: chords, notation

What does E+ mean? I am playing Some Enchanted Evening and this is added along with a C note.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` signifies that the 5th is "augmented" or raised a half step. So "E+" indicates an E augmented triad.

An E (major) triad is:

`note   | E | G# | B
degree | 1 | 3  | 5`

But an E augmented triad has a raised 5th:

`note   | E | G# | B#
degree | 1 | 3  | #5`

Answer (score 3):

It's simply they symbol for an augmented chord which contains a root, Major 3rd, and an Augmented 5th. The note would not be a C, but a B♯ since the 5th of an E chord is some type of B rather than some type of C.

Here's what it would look like in close position:

```
X:1
L:1/1
M:none
K:E
V:1 clef=treble
"E+"[E G ^B] |
%
```